# Is there a way to include a library, such as Angular Material, in my own custom library?

Tags: angular, libraries, storybook

I am trying to use storybook with this library and have a test component that uses the MatRadioModule from Material. I get the following error in my Jest unit test.

Template parse errors:
    'mat-radio-button' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-radio-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-radio-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

My storybook and unit tests work until I try to use Material components, and then it breaks.

Comment: You need to import the MatRadioModule to your test module.

Comment: I do have MatRadioModule imported in the test module, but it is still not finding it. Could my configuration be wrong in using Material to where it won't find any of Material's components?

Answer (score 0):

this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53359350/9983888).

In general, code that your libraries depend on should be added to the `peerDependencies` in the `package.json` of that library.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have @angular/material in the dependencies of my package.json. I read that this is possible, but am still having no luck finding material components. Is something else needed for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to import the Angular Component into the spec file and story for those frameworks to work with Material.