# How do I configure my Angular library to depend on Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I have installed Angular Material into my library and have created a shared resource module that imports and exports all of Materials components. Right now I have a folder that contains a module and a component. The module declaration/exports contains the component and the imports array imports the shared Material module.

For some reason the component will not create a story in storybook and will not pass any unit tests because it cannot find the MatRadioModule that was imported from the shared resource.

This is the error that I get:

Template parse errors:
    'mat-radio-button' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-radio-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-radio-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Here is the Material Module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Angular Material Components
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Here is the component module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [ButtonComponent]
})
export class ButtonModule { }
```

Here is the component with html:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Radios with ngModel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'nds-button',
  templateUrl: 'button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['button.component.css'],
})
export class ButtonComponent {

}
```

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Now I'm just wondering why mat-radio-button would not be a known element?

I should also add that the build works, but failure comes when using Storybook and running my Jest unit tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Angular Material to a custom library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359301/add-angular-material-to-a-custom-library)

Comment: No, none of that stuff worked for me unfortunately. I am not using an app and only want a library that uses Storybook for visualization. I tried adding "@angular/material": "~9.2.1" and "@angular/cdk": "~9.2.1" to peerDependencies and Dependencies, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

this question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53359350/9983888).

Generally speaking, you need to add `@angular/material` as a peer dependency of your library and then call the library from your component. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am placing @angular/material in as a dependency instead of peerDependency. I have no app associated with my library, as I am using Storybook for my visualization. Is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to import the Material Module into the storybook and spec file. This is why it couldn't find the components in the tests or storybook

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the context.

You should read this from beginning till end. It's the answer to your question:

https://angularexperts.io/blog/angular-template-context/

I had the same error and managed my libraries component with the following Decoration:

```
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        MatButtonModule,
    ],
```

I did not declare, import or export anything in the `my-lib.module.ts` of my library

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [],
    exports: []
})
```

Important: Do not add the component to the `declarations` of your main `app.modules.ts` by fault. Only add the Library Module to the `imports` of the app.modules.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        // <-- do not add the lib component here
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MyLibModule
    ]
```